# Copy filtered data from database/excel connection without clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, database, clipboard

I have a large excel file. In a second one, I create a database/excel connection with excel to get the data (Data=> From Excel File=> Load). My second file therefore looks like this:

[image: ex1]

Now I want to only select those entries, where Column3 (C) is not empty. So I click on filter and the result is:

[image: ex2]

This is what I want. However, I now want to copy these data to a new sheet, however I do NOT want to use copy and paste as values or ctrl c and ctrl v, because I am suspicious that with the large data I have the clipboard cannot save enough values and data is lost. (Furthermore this is not really traceable, but that is a minor issue.)

So my first question is: How can I transform this database/excel connection data into "normal table" data with only those records where column c is not empty, avoiding any clipboard / ctrl c ctrlv solution?

My second question is about the approach I tried to achieve this:
If data would be in "normal data" format, so not database/excel file connection, I could use a simple vba code:

```
Sub remove()
Application.ScrenUpdating = False
Columns("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.SreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works on normal data. But not if it is a database/excel connection, I get an error. Is there a way to get this working applied on this "database/excel connection data format"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Power Query From Workbook

Try the following:

- In `Excel`, select `Data > Get Data > From File > From Workbook` and select a file and select `Import`.
- In the opened `Navigator` window, on the left choose a worksheet and on the bottom right press `Edit`. The `Power Query Editor` opens.
- If the empty cells of your column are presented as `null` then right-click the column header and choose `Replace Values`.
- In the opened `Replace Values` window, enter `null` into the `Value To Find` text box and press `OK`.
- Click on the filter arrow located on the right of the column header and select `Remove Empty`.
- In `Power Query Editor`, select `File > Close & Load`. The `Power Query Editor` closes and the data is copied to a table in a new worksheet.